# When I redirect Maven commands, the file looks wrongly encoded

Tags: command-line, 17.10, encoding, maven-3

When I run a Maven command, it's normal in the terminal. But there is a problem when I redirect the output to a file like this:

```
mvn install > file.log
```

When I open the file, I see:

```
[[1;34mINFO[m] Scanning for projects...
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? My Ubuntu is 17.10.

Comment: The program `mvn`, whatever it is, wants to colorize its output and seems to do this even if standard output is not a terminal. Look for an option to disable colorizing the output.

Comment: They look like ANSI color codes - have you tried running in batch (`-B`) mode as described here [Maven CLI Options Reference](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-embedder/cli.html) ?

Comment: @AlexP thanks, you're righth. If you want response.

Comment: @AlexP put the -B in your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program `mvn`, whatever it is, wants to colorize its output and seems to do this even if standard output is not a terminal. Look for an option to disable colorizing the output.

Hat tip to @Douglas: it appears that the required option is `mvn -B`.